# Fragmentar horizontalmente una tabla Access

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access-2013

Buenos días,

Vengo a ustedes por una duda grande que tengo. Estoy viendo una materia que tiene que ver con base de datos distribuidas, y se nos mando a realizar un pequeño ejercicio, con una base de datos Access... Se nos manda crear una base de datos, dividirla y aplicar el concepto de fragmentacion.

Yo hice 2 maquinas virtuales en VMWare, dividi la base de datos entre esas dos maquinas ya:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los cambios se efectuan correctamente.. Ahora viene el asunto:

Quiero separar (o fragmentar) la tabla clientes horizontalmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra en estas tablas hecha en word:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Osea, quiero generar subtablas... empleadoA para una "sucursal" (Via España -
 maquina virtual uno) y empleadoB para la otra "sucursal" (5 de Mayo - maquina virtual dos). Todo esta division que se maneje bajo la columna "codEmpleado". Osea, que cada base de datos tenga su tabla de empleados respectiva de acuerdo a la sucursal en donde se encuentra. He visto algunos videos de como realizar fragmentacion en SQLServer, MySql, pero con Access, no he encontrado en ningun lado...

Les agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Comment: es que access... estoy un 90% seguro, que no permite hacer estas cosas. Access es una base de juguete casi, no preparada para este tipo de cosas.

Comment: @gbianchi Ni siquiera sabía que seguía existiendo, desde que está SQLServer Express :S. Sé que se puede dividir en varios archivos, pero no sé si horizontalmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, lo que estás necesitando hacer es crear una tabla en base a datos existentes en otra tabla.
No dispongo de la versión de Access en la cual estás trabajando así que no puedo probar lo que te estoy sugiriendo, pero a lo mejor investigando un poco lo siguiente podes encontrar una solución:

[Crear una consulta de creación de tabla](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Crear-una-consulta-de-creaci%C3%B3n-de-tabla-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b)

Lo siguiente es un extracto textual del sitio al que apunta el enlace anterior (agregado por sugerencia de lois6b).

> Una consulta de creación de tabla recupera datos de una o varias tablas y después carga el conjunto de resultados en una nueva tabla. Esa nueva tabla puede residir en la base de datos que ha abierto o puede crearla en otra base de datos.

1. En la pestaña **Crear** del grupo **Consultas**, haga clic en **Diseño de consulta**. Nota: Si está usando Access 2007, en la pestaña **Crear** del grupo **Otros**, deberá hacer clic en **Diseño de consulta**.
2. En el cuadro de diálogo **Mostrar tabla**, haga doble clic en las tablas de las que desee recuperar datos. Cada tabla aparece como una ventana en la sección superior del diseñador de consultas. Haga clic en **Cerrar** cuando termine de agregar tablas.
3. En cada tabla, haga doble clic en los campos que desee usar en la consulta. Cada campo aparece en una celda en blanco de la fila **Campo** de la cuadrícula de diseño. Esta figura muestra la cuadrícula de diseño con varios campos de tabla agregados:

[image: Consulta con tres campos en la cuadrícula de diseño]

4. De forma opcional, agregue expresiones a la fila **Campo**.
5. Si lo desea, agregue criterios a la fila **Criterios** de la cuadrícula de diseño.
6. Haga clic en **Ejecutar**[image: Imagen del botón] para ejecutar la consulta y mostrar los resultados en una hoja de datos.
7. Si lo desea, modifique los campos, las expresiones o los criterios y después vuelva a ejecutar la consulta hasta que devuelva los datos que desee colocar en la nueva tabla.

## Convertir la consulta de selección

1. Abra la consulta de selección en la **vista Diseño**, o bien, cambie a la vista Diseño. Access permite hacerlo de varias maneras:

   - Si la consulta está abierta en una hoja de datos, haga clic con el botón secundario del mouse en la pestaña de documentos de la consulta y haga clic en **Vista Diseño**.
   - Si la consulta está cerrada, en el panel de exploración, haga clic con el botón derecho en la consulta y haga clic en **Vista Diseño** en el menú contextual.
2. En el grupo **Tipo de consulta** de la pestaña **Diseño**, haga clic en **Crear tabla**.

Aparecerá el cuadro de diálogo Crear tabla.

[image: El cuadro de diálogo Crear tabla en Access le permite seleccionar opciones para su consulta de creación de tabla.]

3. En el cuadro **Nombre de la tabla**, escriba el nombre de la nueva tabla.

   - O bien -

   Haga clic en la flecha desplegable y seleccione un nombre de tabla existente.
4. Siga uno de estos procedimientos:

   - **Colocar la nueva tabla en la base de datos activa**

     1. Si aún no está seleccionada la opción **Base de datos activa**, haga clic en ella y, a continuación, haga clic en **Aceptar**.
     2. Haga clic en **Ejecutar**[image: Imagen del botón] y después en **Sí** para confirmar la operación.

        > NOTA: Si está reemplazando una tabla existente, Access elimina primero esa tabla y le pide que confirme su eliminación. Haga clic en Sí y, a continuación, haga de nuevo clic en Sí para crear la nueva tabla.
   - **Colocar la nueva tabla en otra base de datos**

     1. Haga clic en **Otra base de datos**.
     2. En el cuadro **Nombre de archivo**, escriba la ubicación y el nombre de archivo de la otra base de datos.

        - O bien -
        Haga clic en **Examinar**, use el cuadro de diálogo **Crear tabla** para buscar la otra base de datos y, a continuación, haga clic en **Aceptar**.
5. Haga clic en **Aceptar** para cerrar el primer cuadro de diálogo **Crear tabla**.
6. Haga clic en **Ejecutar**[image: Imagen del botón] y después en **Sí** para confirmar la operación.

> NOTA: Si está reemplazando una tabla existente, Access elimina primero esa tabla y le pide que confirme su eliminación. Haga clic en Sí y, a continuación, haga de nuevo clic en Sí para crear la nueva tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente: Encuentra la manera de registrar la sucursal donde se encuentran ya sea por su perfil o por la ip de la maquina eso es a tu criterio despues crea una funcion en un modulo de access donde se retorne el valor del id de la sucursal, y en el formulario de access mediante un query manda a llamar la funcion el where debe quedar algo asi "WHERE id_Sucursal= miSucursal()" esto hara que cada uno tenga los datos requeridos por sus sucursales y ahi si borrar o eliminan solo afectaran aquellos dentro de su rango porfavor notificame si esta informacion te ayudo.

Comment: Orlando, se agradece tu contribución pero es importante revises [answer], saludos!